# Tensorflow tf.estimator.Estimator with QueueRunner

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm rewriting my to code to use tf.estimator.Estimator as an encapsulating object for my models.
The problem is :
 I don't see how typical input pipeline fits into the picture.

My input pipeline use queues which are coordianted by `tf.train.Coordinator`.

To satisify `tf.estimator.Estimator` requirements i create all the "input graph"  in `init_fn` function that is passed to estimator when calling:

```
Estimator.train(...)
```

It looks like this
`input_fn(f)`:

```
...create input graph...
qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue, [operations...])
tf.train.add_queue_runner(qr)
```

The problem is: in such scenario how can I start and stop `queue runners`, respectivly at the start and beginning of the Estimator.train(...)?

**Starting**

I figured out for starting the queues I can pass and `init_fn` that does it to scaffold object passed to Estimator.

However how to join threads and close them gracefully - this I do not know.

Is there reference architecture for proper threaded input pipeline when using tf.estimator.?

Is Estimator class even ready to work with queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Estimator` uses `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` which handles starting and joining threads. You can check a couple example input-fns, such as
`tf.estimator.inputs.*`, `tf.contrib.learn.io.read*`